# Cannot solve "ArgumentError: Missing block" when calling form_for in Rails namespaced Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

In the admin panel of an app, there should be a new form introduced. I wanted to make use of *2.3 Relying on Record Identification* as described in [RoR Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification), but if I say

```
form_for(@product)
```

or

```
form_for [:backend, @product]
```

it throws an `ArgumentError: Missing block`. This is for the backend-new function, which the controller in `controller/backend/product_controller` defines via

```
 def new
   @product = Product.new
end
```

What did I do wrong? Why is this not working?

Comment: Can you show us your whole `form_for` line? "Missing block" sound like you forgot to say `form_for @product do |f|` and then close the form with an `end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a do block to the form_for:
(See the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

For example:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem.. I just thought I could have more automagic, a settings db with a lot of columns to generate a form for this.. But while doing it manually it turned out that at a later point I would have to do it manually anyway :)